# python win32com to trim excel cell value with leading spaces

Tags: trim, win32com, cellspacing

Code syntax for win32com to trim excel cell value with leading spaces?

In VBA is trim(cells(1,1).value)

Comment: As opposed to python's in-built `strip()` method?

Comment: I get error message when using it. AttributeError: NoneType object has not attribute strip

Comment: It gave me that error because the cell value was blank, no content to strip from, but strip() work. Thx

Comment: Yes, just wrap the process up in a test - e.g. check the length of the contents of the cell - and run strip if length > 0. Then you won't get NoneType error.